# Open url with curl, click on ajax button, wait and get response html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am going to scrape http://www.car4you.at/Haendlersuche
it shows 20 results first time and pagination. I scrape 20 links successfully but facing problem to get link to next page because there is no link in **href** of pagination. It contains a javascript function.

```
href="javascript:AjaxCallback_ResList('ResultList', 'Pager', '1_1874')"
```

My question is how can I load page with curl then click on next page button, wait for response then parse it.

Here is what I am trying

function of curl

```
function postCurlReq($loginActionUrl,$parameters,$referer)
{
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL,$loginActionUrl); 
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters); 
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('cookie.txt')); // cookie.txt should be in same directoy, where calling script is 
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('cookie.txt'));
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i586; de; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');            
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);   // set referer
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);// ssl certificate
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        $result['EXE'] = curl_exec($this->curl);
        $result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($this->curl);
        $result['ERR'] = curl_error($this->curl);
        return $result;                 
}
```

and tried code is for pagination

```
$loginUrl = "http://www.car4you.at/Haendlersuche";
$parameters = array("href" => "javascript:AjaxCallback_ResList('ResultList', 'Pager', '1_1874')");
$referer = "http://www.car4you.at/Haendlersuche";

$loginHTML = $crawler->postCurlReq($loginUrl,$parameters,$referer);

if ( empty($loginHTML['ERR']) ) { // if no error occure in opening url

print_r($loginHTML['EXE']);

}
```

second method to scrape is select list that show results like
10
20
50
if my script succeed to select 50 then it ll also be happy work
and tried code is for select list

```
$loginUrl = "http://www.car4you.at/Haendlersuche";
$parameters = array("value" => "50");
$referer = "http://www.car4you.at/Haendlersuche";

$loginHTML = $crawler->postCurlReq($loginUrl,$parameters,$referer);

if ( empty($loginHTML['ERR']) ) { // if no error occure in opening url

print_r($loginHTML['EXE']);

}
```

Comment: exactly the same problem i am facing right now!

Comment: hmmmm if you get solution please provide here too

Comment: m sorry! i really dont have one! i shifted to a page which isnt having pagination!

Comment: You can't run javascript with cURL in PHP, you have to figure out what and where the request goes, or use a headless browser to fake the user actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scraping a site you aren't running a browser, just picking up the HTML response from the site. This means that you can't just run JavaScript code, you'd have to parse it yourself, or perhaps use a library to parse it for you.

However any AJAX buttons that fetch more results are just calling another URL (perhaps with GET or POST variables), and themselves parsing the result, or sticking it somewhere in the HTML of the page. You can work out what URL calls are being made using Developer Tools in Chrome, or Firebug etc.. Then you can scrape these URLs instead of the original one, to extract the information.

In this particular case it is quite tricky because there are a number of POST variables on the AJAX request, and spotting the pattern isn't trivial, but it is possible, and probably easier than trying to emulate the JavaScript.

In general, if you really really want to simulate the running of JavaScript in scraping, it is possible to run a browser, and interact with it programatically. This is what [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) does, and I suspect something like this could be done fairly painlessly with Selenium. It's probably still easier to do it by sniffing the AJAX request though.

Comment: Thanks gandaliter for detailed answer

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps.